# return the miaximum date for each stock name in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply, series

I am trying to apply a function which returns the latest or maximum date for a stock (on which I have collected prices for multiple days).

I will use this maximum or latest date to go and collect more prices.

my dataframe is currently in the form:

```
in: df.head()
columns: index(date) | stock_name
2015-10-01              A
2015-10-02              A
2015-10-05              B
2015-10-08              B

def max(x):
return x.idxmax()

df["stock_name"].apply(max)
out:
A 2015-10-02
B 2015-10-08
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I cannot figure out the correct syntax to return the MAX Date for each stock name?

Comment: `df.groupby('stock_name')['date'].max()` may be?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is [`DataFrame.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group based on the `'stock_name'` field. But to get the max, you may first need to reset the index (if the date is the index, if not just don't do the `reset_index()` in the below code and use the column name for the date column) . Example -

```
df.reset_index().groupby('stock_name')['index'].max()  #Use `'date'` instead of `'index'` if the name of `index` is `'date'` .
```

Demo -

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
           stock_name
2015-10-01          A
2015-10-02          A
2015-10-05          B
2015-10-08          B

In [28]: df.reset_index().groupby('stock_name')['index'].max()
Out[28]:
stock_name
A    2015-10-02
B    2015-10-08
Name: index, dtype: object
```